# Solve an equation for a particular variable using Wolfram Alpha

Tags: algebra-precalculus, online-resources, wolfram-alpha

I want to express variable from equation in WolframAlpha web. I tried several keywords but it didn't work. For example I have equation

$$y=x+z+k,$$

and I want Wolfram to rewrite it for variable $x$, $x=y-z-k$. Is it possible and how?

Comment: You know, you could just do it in your head in a matter of seconds...

Comment: check this out: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%2Bz%2Bk it gives you "solution for z" and "alternate form", this latter as usual.

Comment: May be this belongs to [Mathematica Stackexchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is not a particularly good question but it is certainly not off topic, as claimed by the close voters. In fact, the use of mathematical software tools is  *explicitly* listed as on topic in the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and there is a [wolfram-alpha tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha). Use of the WolframAlpha website is explicitly off-topic on the [Mathematica SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), however.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [following query](http://goo.gl/NwzZDQ):

```
solve(y=x+z+k,x)
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't this work for more complex problems such as solve((ax+by)/(cx+dy)=8,x)

Answer (score 1):

To complete my previous comment, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solution+for+variable+x+of%3A+y%3Dx%2Bz%2Bk) is what you may type to achieve what you asked.

I just copied and pasted your equation in WolphramAlpha, the remaining "syntax" was suggested to me by the usual WA output page ("solution for variable $x$").